# CSS - Keeping width of elements

Tags: css, dynamic, width

Is there a css-rule to make the parent `<div>` keep its size (depending on elements) after scaling the window? To make it more clear, here's an example:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
        text1
    </div>
    <div style="width: 60px; height: 30px;">
        text2
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
        text3
    </div>
</div>
```

This code should bring up a div with 3 smaller div's inside. Now when you resize the window, the individual children will be "broken" into new lines.

How could I prevent this behaviour? Using a `min-width` won't work, because I want to have the width dynamic, adding and removing children should be possible. The only option that came to my mind was to count the children via javascript and then set the `min-width` attribute via javascript. But this should be possible to handle with css, I think.

Comment: So you want these divs to stay side-by-side?

Comment: Yes, not wrapping them to seperate lines. `white-space: nowrap;` solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the parent div. I think that will keep them on the same line. On the example you provided you also need:

```
display: inline;
```

on the child divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/9dzBy/

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching something like this for about an hour and didn't find something. Worked!